# Move sprite in AndEngine Without digitalonscreencontrol

Tags: android, andengine

I would like to make the program that when the user pressed the right side of the screen animation moved to the right and when on left that to the left. 
Here code dont work

```
if (pSceneTouchEvent.getY() > 400)
 {
     AnimatedSprite _AnimSprite = new AnimatedSprite(70, 400, _TiledSprite_TR);
_AnimSprite.registerEntityModifier(new MoveModifier(5, 70, Camera_width
     -  _AnimSprite.getWidth(), 400, 400));
                        _AnimSprite.animate(50);
                        xPos = _TiledSprite_TR.getTexturePositionX();
  }
                    else
     {
                        if ((pSceneTouchEvent.getY() < 400)&& 
  pSceneTouchEvent.getY() > 0))
      {
                            AnimatedSprite _AnimSprite = new 
       AnimatedSprite(70, 400, _TiledSprite_TR);
                            _AnimSprite.registerEntityModifier(new MoveModifier(5, 
             400, Camera_width - _AnimSprite.getWidth(), 70, 400));
                            _AnimSprite.animate(50);
                            xPos = _TiledSprite_TR.getTexturePositionX();       
               }
                        else{                                   
              Sprite _Sprite = new Sprite(xPos, 400, _Sprite_TR);
                                MainScene.attachChild(_Sprite);
                            }
                            }
```

Comment: What are your CAMERA_WIDTH AND CAMERA_HEIGHT set to? I'd suggest using relative values for your width and height in your if statements.

Answer (score 0):

Why pSceneTouchEvent.getY()? That's up/down, not left/right. I think you are probably always touching an area that has the Y coordinate less than 400. Try replacing with getX() and see what happens.

Comment: Thats don't work(( May be i can use invisible big digital control, but i don't know how i can change control size.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are generating a new sprite each time the screen is touched. This is probably not what you want to do. I'd suggest that you extend your main class (Usually your BaseGameActivity or similar activity) to use the IOnSceneTouchListener so that you can both access the touch data and have access to your animatedSprites, instead of creating a new IOnSceneTouchListener which can't access any of your animatedSprites.

```
public class Game extends BaseGameActivity implements IOnSceneTouchListener
{
        private AnimatedSprite animatedSprite;
        @Override
    public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) 
    {
        // Access your animated sprites here and make them move based on the touch data
        return true;
    }
}
```

Something along those lines.